# Rails - passing parameters to session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I do not want the parameters to be shown in url. Therefore an option

```
<%= link_to mem, edit_group_member_groups_path(:grp_mem => mem)%>
```

does not suit me.

Till now I have saved the parameters in browser cookies by doing this:

```
<script>
$( function() {         
    $(".grp_member").on("click", function(e) {     
        $.cookie("grp_mem",$(this).attr("grp_mem"),{ path: '/' });                              
    });
})
</script>

<%= link_to mem, edit_group_member_groups_path, :grp_mem => mem, :class => "grp_member" %>
```

BUT everybody can modify the browser cookie and get not allowed information.

So, my next idea is to save the parameters in session . However, I do not know how to pass the parameters to session without url. Is it possible to do with javascipt as well? If yes, how? Or is there another options to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of link_to, build a form which will submit to a new action in your controller which will setup the session value and redirect to the correct page.

Comment: I might imagine that it might work if I had had only one mem, but I have severals <%
members.each do |mem,opt|
%> <%= link_to mem %> <%end%>. Meaning that I need a form for every mem? Somehow I cannot imagine it

Comment: You can build mini-form for every one of them. :)

Comment: could you provide a small example? Is it something like <%= form_for mem, :url=>{:controller => "groups",:action=> "store in session"} %>

Comment: Another option is to create link_to with visible param, and the action will react to it by saving to session and redirecting to same page without this param, however this is much less secure than form.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put things in the session on the client side. Even if you use cookies as a session storage (this is the default by the way), because Rails verifies the session cookie.

Putting lots of things in the session is not good practice because it can grow your request size (since the session cookie is sent on every request). As it was mentioned in the comments you could use a form. Rails provides a convenience wrapper for this purpose: [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

You could use it as a drop in replacement for your `link_to`

```
<%= button_to mem, { action: :edit, controller: :member_groups }, 
              { :class => "grp_member", params: { grp_mem: mem } } %>
```

Or

```
<%= button_to mem, edit_group_member_groups_path, 
              { :class => "grp_member", params: { grp_mem: mem } } %>
```

And you have to make sure your `edit` action can handle the `POST` request and it does not need any url path params.

You can specify extra params according to [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10471/files).

Comment: the only parameters I get while using button_to are Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ldRS+RCi82LYZtOXHy9Xj1XpkaWDc9micjjedlD9n2I=", "locale"=>"en"} and no grp_mem. So I do not know how to catch grp_mem

Comment: @Tonja sorry for the lots of edits, after checking the code there is a way to specify arbitrary form params.

Comment: if I print out params I get again this: params {"authenticity_token"=>"ldRS+RCi82LYZtOXHy9Xj1XpkaWDc9micjjedlD9n2I=", "action"=>"edit_group_member", "controller"=>"groups", "locale"=>"en"}  It does not have a grip_mem